# Cassandra order by and filter through secondary indexes

Tags: cassandra, cql

My cassandra table structure is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE sujata
          ... (ID int, roll_number int, age int, PRIMARY KEY (ID,roll_number));
```

I had inserted some of the records where ID acts as a partition for a number of rows. I am performing the following query:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM sujata WHERE ID=1 ORDER BY roll_number ASC and age=24 Allow Filtering;
```

I am getting the following error:

```
missing EOF at 'and' (...1 ORDER BY roll_number ASC [and] age...)">
```

I don't know if it possible to filter out the results after performing order by. Please suggest where am i missing. Thank you.

Comment: Try this :  SELECT count(*) FROM sujata WHERE ID=1 and age=24 ORDER BY roll_number ASC  Allow Filtering

Comment: The above query won't work because order by is not supported on secondary indices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Don't use ALLOW FILTERING.  It doesn't perform or
   scale, because it allows you to query Cassandra in ways that it is
   not designed to support.
2. CQL is interpreting your statement as `ORDER BY
   roll_number ASC and age=24` as you trying to ORDER BY two things. 
   The AND belongs in your WHERE clause, and needs to be specified
   *before* ORDER BY.
3. Cassandra uses your clustering keys to write your data's
   on-disk sort order.  ORDER BY only allows you to flip the sort
   direction (ascending vs. descending) of your clustering order.  So
   if you have already specified the correct sort order in your table
   definition, then you don't need to specify ORDER BY.
4. To query your table by both `ID` and `age`, you need to
   design your PRIMARY KEY with those two columns as the first two. 
   You can only query on columns defined in your PRIMARY KEY (secondary
   indexes not withstanding), and then only in the same order (you
   can't skip keys).  To accomplish this, I created a query table
   (`sujataByIDAndAge`) that looks like this:

.

```
CREATE TABLE sujataByIDAndAge (
    ID int, 
    roll_number int, 
    age int, 
PRIMARY KEY (ID,age,roll_number));
```

Now after inserting a few rows:

```
aploetz@cqlsh:stackoverflow> INSERT INTO sujatabyidandage  (id, roll_number, age) 
                             VALUES (2, 20, 26);
aploetz@cqlsh:stackoverflow> INSERT INTO sujatabyidandage  (id, roll_number, age) 
                             VALUES (1, 100, 24);
aploetz@cqlsh:stackoverflow> INSERT INTO sujatabyidandage  (id, roll_number, age) 
                             VALUES (1, 110, 24);
aploetz@cqlsh:stackoverflow> INSERT INTO sujatabyidandage  (id, roll_number, age) 
                             VALUES (1, 190, 24);
```

Now I can run your query, and I don't need to specify ORDER BY or ALLOW FILTERING:

```
aploetz@cqlsh:stackoverflow> SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sujatabyidandage WHERE ID=1 AND age=24;

 count
-------
     3

(1 rows)
```

Also important to mention, is that if result set order is important to you then you must query by the primary keys.  Cassandra only enforces order of results within a partition key (ID in your case).

Comment: Your suggestion seems well. But I wanted the query with a non-primary key. If it is not possible then the query might have resulted with an error but it is showing me some missing EOF. Can you tell me where am i missing.

Comment: @sujata My 2nd point details what is causing your EOF.  CQL is expecting your statement to be over at the `ORDER BY`, yet you have your `AND` after it.

Comment: @sujata You can also fix it by not specifying `ORDER BY` at all (which I mentioned in my 3rd point).

Comment: I have not specified the sort order in my table definition as I have read that cassandra by default orders the data in ascending order. As per docs, if i specify the order by in the query then the retrieval of rows is efficient and faster.

Comment: If my query is `SELECT count(*) FROM sujata WHERE ID=1 ORDER BY roll_number ASC` then the time it takes for fetching 600000 rows is only 19s whereas the query `SELECT count(*) FROM sujata WHERE ID=1 and age=24 ` took around 56s for fetching 160000 rows. Why is this such a huge difference in time??

Comment: 1. If you now wish to know why your queries are not performing as you expect, please ask a new question.  2. Simply put, your interpretation of the documentation is incorrect.

Comment: It's not like how i expect the queries, I wanted a clear definition on whether it is possible for an order by and allow filtering. For this, I got the answer that I cannot do. Thanks